# Using an active record object array to restrain a DB search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a list of business objects listed in the array @businesses

I would like to find a list of employees that work at all the businesses listed in @businesses.

It seems that I can't just do `Employee.where(:business_id=>@businesses)`

Is there a way to do the above that **doesn't involve code like**

```
@businesses.each do |business|
  business.employees
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
Employee.find(:all, :conditions => { :business_id => @businesses.map(&:id) })
```

Or

```
Employee.where(:business_id => @businesses.map(&:id))
```